# How can I get a list of all users who are running my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm creating a Facebook app that enables users to make new friends. To do this, I need to get a list of everyone who has logged in with my app. How do I do this? I've Googled this question, but all I can find is the list of one's friends who have the app installed, not the list of everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for this, you need to store every authorized user in your own database. Make sure you remove users who de-authorized your app - see "Deauthorize Callback URL" in the app settings.